# Set Counter Value

Tags: xml, bash, csv, echo, counter

Hello Programming Profi,
i would like to have the counter value in total and in last in second echo of the script but the counter is runnung in do function.
is there a way to let it write the value before the do function .
or if i write the first 2 echo lines under counter i got the value but i need to write this line on top of xml files!
is there a way to do that , maybe counter value from middel the script to the total and last on echo second line .

```
#XML headers
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' > $tmp_gigabook
echo "<list response=\"get_list\" type=\"pr\" reqid=\"1000\" total=\"$counter\" first=\"1\" last=\"$counter\">" >> $tmp_gigabook
declare counter=1000
# Read intermediate csv-xml-ish into array of lines
readarray -t lines < $tmp_intermediate
# Walk through lines and output entries
for line in "${lines[@]}"
do
    # Split line into columns
    # Fix v 0.3 Parentheses bug: explicitly set IFS, don't rely on defaults
    IFS=$'\t'
    read -a columns <<< "$line"
    # Output xml

((counter++))

    echo "<entry id=\"$counter\">
    <ln>${columns[0]}</ln> 
    <fn>${columns[1]}</fn>
    <mb>${columns[2]}</mb>
    <hm>${columns[3]}</hm>
     </entry>" >> $tmp_gigabook

done
# XML footer
echo '</list>' >> $tmp_gigabook
# Remove placeholders / markers
sed -i 's/±//g' $tmp_gigabook

## Finalise
# Copy and adjust
cp -f $tmp_gigabook $instance/$phonebook
chown phonesystem:phonesystem $instance/$phonebook
chmod 600 $instance/$phonebook
```

Answer (score 0):

You could defer printing out your header until after you are done processing the file and print that along with the file contents using `cat` back into the file:

```
# remove echo statements for the header, create the blank file first
echo -n >"$tmp_gigabook" # or :>"$tmp_gigabook"

# snip - declare / readarray here

for line in "${lines[@]}"
do
   # snip - write to file as usual
done
# XML footer
echo '</list>' >> "$tmp_gigabook"

# rewrite the file but prepend the header information w/counter values
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<list response=\"get_list\" type=\"pr\" reqid=\"1000\" total=\"$counter\" first=\"1\" last=\"$((counter-1000))\">
$(cat "$tmp_gigabook")" > "$tmp_gigabook"
```